# Rails 4 Asset Pipeline: Compile both with and without fingerprint

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline

Rails 4 has changed the way assets are fingerprinted (for browser cache busting):

```
Old Strategy: application.css?12345
Rails 3.2:    application-12345.css and application.css
Rails 4.0:    application-12345.css
```

While this makes perfect sense, it's a problem if the stylesheets are used by another service (in our case Zendesk). This external site needs the CSS from the Rails app, but it doesn't know the fingerprint (aka: digest).

Is there a way to compile all assets both with and without fingerprint? Or maybe another approach to tackle this?

Comment: The precompilation process creates a manifest JSON file which includes details about the fingerprinted files. The manifest file itself is fingerprinted, but perhaps you could ship it out somewhere as part of a compilation task?

Comment: Have a separate stylesheet for zendesk and don't put it in the asset digest? application stylesheet should not really be serving an external app that is not part of the application?

Comment: @Zabba Believe me, it makes sense to use the stylesheet for Zendesk in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've written a rake task to get the un-fingerprinted files à la Rails 3.2 back:

```
namespace :assets do
  desc "Create symlinks without cache busting digest"
  task :create_symlinks_without_digest => :environment do
    Dir.glob(Rails.root.join('public', 'assets', '**', '*')).each do |item|
      if File.file?(item) && item.match(/-[a-f0-9]{32}/)
        FileUtils.ln_s Pathname(item).basename, item.sub(/-[a-f0-9]{32}/, '')
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Worth pointing out that for me, on Rails 4.2, the fingerprints are 64 not 32 characters

Comment: Quite late, yes, but there is a gem for doing it:  https://github.com/alexspeller/non-stupid-digest-assets