# Compile sass stylsheets in Rails without fingerprinting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, sass, asset-pipeline

I need to use my sass stylesheets for another non-rails site (a Wordpress blog), so I need to compile them into a css file without the file fingerprinting from the asset pipeline. I saw this related post:

[Rails 4 Asset Pipeline: Compile both with and without fingerprint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23544904/rails-4-asset-pipeline-compile-both-with-and-without-fingerprint)

However, it doesn't seem to give me the non-fingerprinted stylesheet I'm looking for

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17536023/rake-assetsprecompilenodigest-in-rails-4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rails 4 has documentation for this.
Just set

```
config.assets.digest = false
```

in your environment configuration file (for example `config/environments/production.rb`)

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#turning-digests-off

Comment: Great, thanks! When I made this change, only my css file was un-fingerprinted, but once I made a change to my sass all fingerprints in the css were removed.

Answer (score 2):

There is a gem called [non-stupid-digest-assets](https://github.com/alexspeller/non-stupid-digest-assets) which allows you to determine which files are "fingerprinted" and which are not.

```
#config/initializers/non_digest_assets.rb
NonStupidDigestAssets.whitelist = ["your_file.js"]
```

You'll then be able to call it `your_file.js` as well as using asset_path `asset_path("your_file.js")`